# Thanks to let me write "lagrangian" in lowercase

Tags: discussion, editing

Thank you for your attempt to edit my post better, and I appreciate every edit you make. However please keep in mind that I intentionally use *lagrangian*, not *Lagrangian*.

I know that *Lagrangian* is widely accepted and if I write it differently, you will find something not right, and you have the itch to fix it. When you read the words, you are not spelling every character it has, but recognizing it as a whole gesture. By remember the whole gesture, your speed of reading will be enhanced, therefore your brain saves the energy for other task, such as truly understanding the text. That's why misspelling words are irritated because it interrupts your reading flows. Seeing it lowercased while you expecting it uppercased makes you feel the same.

However, I have my own rationale. *Google* is a company name, a proper noun, but *google* is a verb; *Fermi* is a person name, a proper noun, but *fermion* is a noun. I think writing *lagrangian* in lowercase is not wrong; In his book, Quantum Mechanics and Path Integral, Feynmann also wrote *lagrangian* in lowercase.

I'm not saying that you are absolutely wrong, nor I'm absolutely right. There is no wrong or right in languages, just majority and minority. Therefore I don't mind if seeing *Lagrangian*. However, please let me write it in the way I feel right. Thank you for your understanding and sorry if this makes any inconvenience.

I don't mind if you downvote this. I preset this line below so that every time I foresee that someone will uppercase *lagrangian*, *hamiltonian*, etc, all I need is just copy this line into my post.
`<!-NOTE: I intentionally write "lagrangian" in lowercase. See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6257/41634->`

Comment: Lol. Honestly, I don't think this is really important enough to have a discussion on. You can just roll-back any edits that violate your preferred capitalization convention on your own posts.

Comment: I think you'd better ask why it's written capitalized at [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/), so that you'd hopefully get satisfied with knowledge of the reasons, rather than insist on incorrect writing. BTW, in other languages these all words are written non-capitalized, e.g. in [Russian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD)

Comment: @Ruslan: the rule depends on the language you are talking to. For example, in Germany, all nouns are capitalized. This [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/should-the-word-boolean-be-capitalized) on English.SE doesn't have any answer that really explain what should I do.

Comment: Of course, I didn't mean that in all other languages they are not capitalized, just gave you an example.

Comment: @Danu What, not important enough? Either one of the two is correct, so it is good to know which one is.

Comment: @Bernhard: While the accepted convention is the *Lagrangian*, it really isn't up to Physics.SE to decide what is the accepted version. Thus, this really isn't an important issue.

Comment: @KyleKanos Yeah, I found your Merriam-Webster reference quite convincing. Wonder where the downvotes come from.

Comment: @Bernhard: Very likely due to my being a bit of a jerk with the first half of my answer.

Comment: @KyleKanos: it's not jerk, it's really funny

Answer (score 1):

For starters, check this link for the Wikipedia entry on [*Lagrangian*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian). Then press `CTRL+F` and type in `lagrangian`. Scroll through the page and count the number of times you see the lower-case version of the word. The hidden value below gives you the total number of times it's found, in case you were not interested in doing the experiment.

> There are 0 (**zero**) instances of the lower-case version of the word "lagrangian"

Similar results are found [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath523/kmath523.htm), [here](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/Lagrangian.html), [here](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/stat.mech/lectures/lecture_1/node3.html) and so on. Note also that [Merriam-Webster dictionary capitalizes it as well](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lagrangian).

---

Anyways, if you feel that strongly about using the wrong case, you can always re-edit the question to make it the (incorrect) lower-case.

Comment: In 2000, [*Lagrangian* was used 27-fold than *lagrangian*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lagrangian%2CLagrangian&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clagrangian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLagrangian%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clagrangian%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2CLagrangian%3B%2Cc1) :p

Comment: @Ooker: I'm not sure that the data you link helps your point any.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I just want to be acknowledged that I know that *lagrangian* is hardly to be found.

Comment: @Ooker: Wouldn't that suggest to you that the reason that *lagrangian* is hardly found is because it's wrong?

Comment: No offense, but in the view point of linguistics, can you say what is wrong with *lagrangian*? Its ubiquitousness does not completely prove that it is right. Likewise, [is *atomic bomb* a good name?](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/195/is-atomic-bomb-a-good-name?noredirect=1#comment315_195)

Comment: @Ooker: Linguistically, *Lagrangian* is an adjective formed from a proper noun (Lagrange) which is *always* capitalized (other examples include Fermi-Dirac statistics, Fermi energy, and Debye shielding). See also this [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/should-the-word-boolean-be-capitalized) post.

Comment: And, for good measure, [*The Handbook of Writing for Mathematical Sciences*](http://books.google.com/books?id=tRGBEll3wV4C&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=why+is+lagrangian+capitalized&source=bl&ots=n0dF-O7x-n&sig=YHUgC55YFl6E39-Uksn87Jj9leg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pORYVImsGoSlNu7ygMgI&ved=0CCwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=why%20is%20lagrangian%20capitalized&f=false) states *Words that are derived from a person's name inherit the capitalization*.

Comment: But why *fermion*, not *Fermion*?

Comment: @Ooker: Because fermion is a *noun*, not an *adjective*.

Comment: From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian): "The Lagrangian, L, of a dynamical system is **a mathematical function**". I don't think a function could possibly be an adjective.

Comment: @Ooker well you'd have then to also rename Hamiltonian, Laplacian, d'Alembertian, Routhian and other *ians common in physics and mathematics.

Comment: @Ruslan: That's what I do. In fact, people are now using *[abelian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group)*

Comment: Yeah, indeed. OTOH, they still use [Riemannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold) if you want an adjective. I guess this is more a historically settled convention.

Comment: @Ooker I think *Lagrangian* is commonly understood to mean *Lagrangian function*, without explicitly expressing the second word out of laziness. This explains the confusion; I think Lagrangian *should* be understood as an adjective.

Comment: *"Words that are derived from a person's name inherit the capitalization."* Annoyingly SI units derived from peoples names *do not* automatically inherit the capital. It's kelvin, not Kelvin according to the committee. http://english.stackexchange.com/q/173906/

Comment: @dmckee But we do abbreviate it with K, just for clarity ;)

Comment: @Danu: (1) I don't think that words end with *-ian* would be an adjective, such as *physician*. (2) In *chicken soup*, *chicken* is a noun, serves as an adjective. It's called **[noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)**

Comment: @Ooker since a language is necessarily defined by how it is used and the people that use it, one could say that if a word is given permanent capitalization and it is agreed on by the vast majority of those that use the word, then regardless the grammatical reasonings, in that language it becomes correct to capitalize the word

Comment: @Jim: you are right. I just want to do the right thing. Maybe I am Don Quixote, or quixotic.